# Syntax explanation for zenburn in shell placed in the .profile or .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash

I found this color scheme to enable zenburn in the bash shell. But I really do not understand what it does. Could someone shed some info as to what exactly this is doing.

```
function EXT_COLOR () { echo -ne "\033[38;5;$1m"; }
export LS_COLORS='di=38;5;108:fi=00:*svn-commit.tmp=31:ln=38;5;116:ex=38;5;186'
export PS1='`EXT_COLOR 187`\u@\h`EXT_COLOR 174` \w \$\[\033[00m\] > '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function sets color (SGR). For more on escape sequences see eg. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)
LS_COLORS sets how to color different files/filetypes. This i never use, you should wait for someone else to answer.

Third line sets your multihued prompt: sets the color by using the function previously defined, outputs username (`\u`), then literal @, then hostname (`\h`), then changes color once again, outputs workdirectory (`\w`), then $ or # (depends on EUID), then sets color back to normal (`\[` and `\]` are used to embed non-printing characters, see man bash/PROMPTING) and finally outputs greater-then symbol.

Comment: `\\$` isn't a literal dollar sign, it's a conditional prompt character that shows `#` if your EUID is 0 or `$` otherwise. The `\[\]` needs to be used around the other escape sequences as well: `EXT_COLOR () { echo -ne "\[\033[38;5;$1m\]"; }`

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Thank you, updated the text and patched my knowledge:)

Comment: Yeah, it ate mine, too. The last sentence in my comment should say: The `\\[\\]` needs to be used around the other escape sequences as well: `EXT_COLOR () { echo -ne "\\[\033[38;5;$1m\\]"; }`

Comment: Ok guys thanks for the explanation. I just was quite sure what I was about to be putting in the .bashrc. Now I just need to figure out the LS_COLORS option

Comment: @capnhud: Have a look at http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors

Comment: @pooh I did look at the link you posted which help alot but with those instructions it seemed the only way I could get colors to show up in the bash shell was to constantly key in ls, when in reality I wanted the colors to just be there in the first place. Using the color scheme that I posted did exactly what I wanted, but just wanted a better understanding of what I was doing. Your explanation helped me to gain a better understanding.